# List does not exist error trying to deploy feature to subsite

Tags: deployment, feature

I have a root site collection and a user control stored in controltemplates. http://root

I have another site collection under here http://root/fs which also uses this user control but uses its own customised control style sheet.

I am trying to deploy a stylesheet into the style library of each, but am getting...

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to instantiate file "fs/Style Library/mega-drop-down.css" from module "FS Style Sheets": The specified list does not exist.
```

for the subsite.

Do i need to specify the site collection elsewhere as it seems to be accessing it as a sub folder rather than a site?

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="FS Style Sheets" Url="fs/Style Library">
    <File Path="FS\styles\mega-drop-down.css" Url="mega-drop-down.css" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way around this, and that is to create a new visual studio sharepoint project, but point the project deployment url to the /fs site. Obviously this has to be unique on a project by project basis.

I'd be interested in an answer that shows deployment & activation to two separate sites from the same project.

Maybe its a just a limitation in VS that only lets you activate to one site - same as you can only choose to have all features in a project activate or not, not selectively on a per feature basis.

Comment: The site for which you choose to deploy a solution to is solely for debugging purposes. If you choose a farm solution to be deployed at `http://x` then the package generated from that will deploy on any other SharePoint 2010 installation using powershell.

Comment: Additionally, the site which you specify to deploy to is not hard coded anywhere within the solution package files at all. Like I said, it's solely used for debugging purposes.

Comment: Finally - are you developing on a production server?

Comment: so VS doesnt use that property as its activation path?

Comment: developing on a local dev server

Comment: (phew, just checking!) - VS will only use it if you deploy from within Visual Studio. Once you take the package to your testing environments you shouldn't have VS on there so it will activate on any site collection you specify through the powershell command line when you deploy the wsp.

Comment: See here how you pass in the activation URL via powershell - http://patrickboom.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/using-powershell-to-deploy-sharepoint-solutions-wsp-2/

Answer (score 4):

Note the Model URL and the File path of the File. Those should point to the same place, for example

```
<Module Name="Pages" Url="Pages">
<File Path="Pages\myPage.aspx" Url="myPage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
```

HTH

Comment: Hmm not in my XP, the Path is only pointing to your own local dev files, they don't have to match

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `fs` in the `Url` attribute of the `Module` element. It's not needed. The Url attribute is site collection relative.

Comment: so how to specify a specific site?

Comment: The feature is activated within the context of a site collection, so you don't need to specify one at all.

Comment: and visual studio makes you specify this, see my answer below

Comment: see my comment on your answer.

Comment: how to i get it to activate in the site /fs then?

Answer (score 0):

1. To use Style Library you need a Publishing site. Or at least a version of that Library taken from a Publishing site.
2. the Style Library, by default is only a Top-Level site library, therefore it doesn't exist at sub-site level.

If you plan to use a module to deploy your styles, use the RootWebOnly=TRUE on the Module which, even if your feature is Web targeted will always deploy only for the TopLevel. Otherwise your feature might look the Web Level for that Library always.

C:\Marius